# How to add an index to an NSMutableArray based on value in another array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I've looked at lots of questions about NS(Mutable)Arrays. I guess I am not grokking the concept, or the questions don't seem relevant.

What I' trying to do is the following:

Incoming Array 1:

Name
Code
Start time
End Time
etc

Incoming Array 2

Code
Ordinal

What I want:

Ordinal
Name
Code
Start time
End Time
etc

This is my code at present:

```
int i=0;
for (i=0; i < stationListArray.count; i++) {
    NSString *slCodeString = [stationListArray[i] valueForKey:@"Code"];
    NSLog(@"slCodeString: %@", slCodeString);
    int j=0;
    for (j=0; j< lineSequenceArray.count; j++) {
        NSString *lsCodeString = [lineSequenceArray[j]valueForKey:@"StationCode"];
        NSLog(@"lsCodeString: %@", lsCodeString);
        if ([slCodeString isEqualToString:lsCodeString]) {
            NSLog(@"match");
            NSString *ordinalString = [lineSequenceArray[j] valueForKey:@"SeqNum"];
            NSLog(@"ordinalString: %@", ordinalString);
            [stationListArray[i] addObject:ordinalString]; <------
        }
    }
}
```

I'm logging the values and they return correctly.
The compiler doesn't like the last statement. I get this error:

```
[__NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f63e13c30
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9f63e13c30'
```

Here is an excerpt from the StationListArray:

```
(
        {
        Address =         {
            City = Greenbelt;
            State = MD;
            Street = ".....";
            Zip = 20740;
        };
        Code = E10;
        Lat = "39.0111458605";
        Lon = "-76.9110575731";
        Name = Greenbelt;
    }   
)
```

Comment: Apparently `stationListArray[i]` is a `NSDictionary`, not a `NSArray`.

Comment: Probably you want to use the  `insertObject:atIndex:` method
documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/

Comment: @Larme. I've added an excerpt from the array to my question.

Comment: Do you want to merge 2 arrays in 1 array ? I don't get what you want

Comment: @Roma-MT, as in my question (could be better formatted), Ordinal, Name, Code, Start time, End Time, etc

Comment: So I was right ? you have an array1 and array2 and you want to insert in array1 the values of array2  ?

Comment: yes. I'd prefer only the ordinal object but merging the arrays would work

Comment: @all I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Ok, Seems like your arrays are contain dictionaries inside of them
So All you need to do is to insert the Ordinal from dictionary in array2 in dictionary from array1.

Comment: Please make this an answer and add a code snip... please!

Comment: @Roma-MT: so something with "(...)" is a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        NSString *ordinalString = [lineSequenceArray[j] valueForKey:@"SeqNum"]; //Is NSString
        [stationListArray[i] addObject:ordinalString];//<----- trying to call addObject method of NSMutableArray on NSDictionary -> Not GOOD
```

When you do `[stationListArray[i]` you get `NSDictionary` in your case 
(Generally it returns an `NSObject` that is inside the `NSArray` at the given index, in your case is `NSDictionary`).

So in order to complete your desired operation: you should make an `NSMutableDictionary` instance (In this case it should be the `mutableCopy` from the `stationListArray[i]`'s `NSObject` which is `NSDictionary`, when you do `mutableCopy` it copies the entire `NSDictionary` and makes it `Mutable`)
make the changes on it and then assign it in to the `stationListArray[i]`

For example:

```
NSMutableDictionary * tempDict = [[stationArray objectAtIndex:i]mutableCopy];//Create a mutable copy of the `NSDictionary` that is inside the `NSArray`
[[tempDict setObject:ordinalString forKey:@"Ordinal"]; //In this line you are adding the Ordinal `NSString` in to the tempDict `NSMutableDictionary` so now you have the desired `NSMutableDictionary`. You can change the key to whatever you wish.
[stationArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[tempDict copy]];//Swap the original(old NSDictionary) with the new updated `NSMutableDictionary` I used the copy method in order to replace it with the IMMUTABLE `NSDictionary`
```

Comment: great. Thanks very much.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte You are welcome! I added some comments to explain the code snippet I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
            [stationListArray[i] addObject:ordinalString]; <------
```

This is not an NSMutableArray. You must use

```
            [stationListArray addObject:ordinalString]; <------
```

instead of the what you have done.

Here is the way you can write a better understandable code because for me the code is not clear.You can also try like this in loop to achieve what you want.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableDictionary *dictMain = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableDictionary *dictAddress = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[dictAddress setValue:@"Greenbelt" forKey:@"City"];
[dictAddress setValue:@"MD" forKey:@"State"];
[dictAddress setValue:@"....." forKey:@"Street"];
[dictAddress setValue:@"20740" forKey:@"Zip"];

[dictMain setValue:dictAddress forKey:@"Address"];
[dictMain setValue:@"E10" forKey:@"Code"];
[dictMain setValue:@"39.0111458605" forKey:@"Lat"];
[dictMain setValue:@"-76.9110575731" forKey:@"Lon"];
[dictMain setValue:@"Greenbelt" forKey:@"Name"];

[array addObject:dictMain];
```

Comment: hmm. I'm loping through stationListArray to perform this function a number [i] of times..